why did Jupyter Lab update to 4.2 fail?
After receiving the respective notification on May 15 2024, I  tried to update Jupyter Lab version 4.0.11 to version 4.2 on my Linux desktop.
I entered:
conda update jupyterlab 

In the terminal. It seemed to proceed normally. Next I entered:
jupyter lab --version

and got the answer: 4.0.11. I then tried to update a second time. This time it told me that:
** All requested packages already installed.** But it still showed version 4.0.11.
How can I update to 4.2?

Probably conda cannot satisfy all the requirements without creating a conflict or downgrading some other package. You may try forcing the installation by
conda install jupyterlab=4.2

This should either give you a conflict or suggest replacing/downgrading some packages in order to proceed with the install.
